# Rootfs is a special instance of ramfs

Tags: linux, boot

In the document present in 
www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt
the author writes that "Rootfs is a special instance of ramfs".

Answer (score 1):

It's a chicken-and-egg kind of problem.

If you want to mount a filesystem, you need a mountpoint to mount it to.

However, a mountpoint is a directory that is provided by another filesystem.

So how did the first mounted filesystem come about?

Without a filesystem, you would not have a `/` root mountpoint to mount the root filesystem to. So to solve this dilemma, the kernel just produces a special instance of a filesystem out of nowhere. It makes sure there always is a `/` mountpoint available.

And it used to be like that, just `/` and nothing else, until someone went and invented initrd/initramfs so nowadays in early boot we build up this magical cardhouse of a fully fledged Linux userland just so we can figure out where your real root filesystem is at.